# Laravel 8 URL string with duplicated URL name as parameter

Tags: nginx, laravel-8

I'm running a Laravel 8 application on an Nginx server. When I use the following...

```
$request->fullUrl()
```

Within my code, the returned string looks as follows.

```
https://servername.tld/name1/name2/name3/name4?%2Fname2%2Fname3%2Fname4=
```

When I open the site...

```
https://servername.tld/name1/name2/name3/name4
```

In my browser. I have no clue why this URL string is generated with a parameter that duplicates the URL passed to the browser. On my local development machine running MAMP, the effect does not show up. Does anyone have any idea what is going on in my Laravel/Nginx system here?

Comment: do you have any rewrite rules for your nginx host ? can you share some information about your host  (server block)